# Comma at the End of a List Following a Colon

Tags: punctuation, commas, colons, style-manuals

Is the following sentence written correctly?

> Bob's three favorite colors: black, red, and blue, are Emma's least favorite colors.

Specifically, I'm asking about the comma following *blue*.

Answer (score 3):

The list of colors is a parenthesis and should have [the same punctuation at both ends](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/parenthesis.htm), beginning with a comma instead of a colon.

> Bob's three favorite colors, black, red, and blue, are Emma's least favorite colors.

However, while *technically* correct, this is not a good stylistic choice. The commas in the parenthesis itself make the use of additional commas awkward, so it is preferred to offset the parenthesis with a different punctuation sign like parentheses (self-demonstrating here) or dashes.

This doesn't look like a formal text, so there is no much preference over one or the other, bear in mind that parentheses are not preferred for formal text as they can make said text look messy

Comment: The coments, unfortunately, have been removed. One can also uses dashes.

Comment: Rearranging it to "Black, red, and blue, Bob's three favorite colors, are Emma's least favorite colors." would be fine, with commas at either end of the parenthesis (which is now "Bob's three favorite colors").